# Twig: Loop Index and Second Value for each Iteration

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, zend-framework2, twig

i got the following loop

```
{% set services = { "ceoCentralServices": ceoCentralServices, "cfoCentralServices": cfoCentralServices, "cooCentralServices": cooCentralServices} %}

    {% for events, serviceEvents in services %}

        {% if serviceEvents %}
        <div class="wrapItFine" style="background:purple;">
            {% for event in serviceEvents %}
                 <div class="dialog" data-index="loop2{{ loop.index0 }}">
                    <li class="contentli">{{ event.value }}</li>
                 </div>
                <div style="display:none;" 
                        id="anmelden_boxloop2{{ counter }}{{ loop.index0 }}" 
                        class="{{ event.value }}{{ loop.index0 }}" >
                    {% include 'ansprechpartnerSingle.twig' %}

                    </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
```

this returns 3 boxes with data-index="loop2+index.
the problem is, that i need in each loop a different value like loop2+index, loop3+index, loop4+index

i tried a set Counter and incrementing in the for loop which returned every time the same value.

feel free to downvote, like everytime :-)

Comment: addit: loop2 needs to be {{ counter }} and should be different in each iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your second loop you can simply use

```
{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 }}
```

to get the index of the parent loop, which you can use instead of your counter

```
 data-index="loop{{ loop.parent.loop.index0 }}{{ loop.index0 }}"
```